# Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option

Tags: routes, vuetify.js

I been trying to add the routing on vuetify but its not working. i looked online and search the error but still unable to fix the error. I don't see any problem with my code but i'm sure there exist come problem which is causing this error

```
i tried these steps at a time:
```

1)
    import Router from 'vue-router'
    Vue.use(Router)
2)
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
    Vue.use(VueRouter)

none of them works for me. Note that I used both steps separately

router.js file contains this code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import Booking from './views/Booking.vue'

// import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
// Vue.use(VueRouter)

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home
      },
      {
        path: '/booking',
        name: 'booking',
        component: Booking
      }
   ]
})

//The App.vue file contains this:
<template>
  <v-app class="grey lighten-4">
    <Navbar />

    <v-content>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>

    <Footer />

  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
export default {
  components: { Navbar, Footer },
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {

    }
  }
}
</script>

//And the Navbar contains this code after the template tag:
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      links: [
        { text: 'Home', route: '/' },
        { text: 'About', route: '/about' },
        { text: 'Booking', route: '/booking' },
        { text: 'Services', route: '/services' },
        { text: 'Pricing', route: '/pricing' }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>


this is the error message i'm getting:

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

First all of change your code back to import and use `VueRouter`.

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

Then you need to to inject the router with the router option to make the whole app router-aware. In your case that would mean the following for App.vue.

```
<template>
  <v-app class="grey lighten-4">
    <Navbar />

    <v-content>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>

    <Footer />

  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import router from '../router.js' // depending on your project structure

export default {
  components: { Navbar, Footer },
  name: 'App',
  router: router, // 
  data () {
    return {

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Source: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript